# "Directly accessing" return values without referencing

Tags: php, ruby, programming-languages, syntax

Look at this ruby example:

```
puts ["Dog","Cat","Gates"][1]
```

This will output `Cat` as ruby allows me to directly access the "anonymous" array created.

If I try this in PHP, however:

```
echo array("Dog","Cat,"Gates")[1]
```

This won't work.

- What is this called, not only concerning arrays but all functions?
- Where else is it possible?

Feel free to change the question title when you know how this "feature" is called.

Comment: The Ruby version should read `puts ["Dog","Cat","Gates"][1]`

Comment: Don't you wish PHP had an object notation too?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no such language construct. It was [proposed for PHP 6](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) but got declined.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, `[]` is just a method call (`obj[1]` is syntactic sugar for `obj.[](1)`) so there's no semantic difference between ["Dog", "Cat", "Gates"][1] and ["Dog", "Cat", "Gates"].slice(1). Many syntactic constructs that appear to be "operators" in Ruby are really methods, and they can generally be defined on your own custom classes.  For example:

```
class Foo
  def [](index)
    puts "you tried to get something at #{index}"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f[12]
```