# Indexing directly into returned array in Perl

Tags: perl

This question has been asked about PHP both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172559/most-efficient-way-to-index-a-returned-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509937/directly-accessing-return-values-without-referencing), and I have the same question for Perl. Given a function that returns a list, is there any way (or what is the best way) to immediately index into it without using a temporary variable?

For example:

```
my $comma_separated = "a,b,c";
my $a = split (/,/, $comma_separated)[0]; #not valid syntax
```

I see why the syntax in the second line is invalid, so I'm wondering if there's a way to get the same effect without first assigning the return value to a list and indexing from that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use parentheses to define your list and then index it to pull your desired element(s):

```
my $a = (split /,/, $comma_separated)[0];
```

Comment: Since in many cases the parenthesis are optional on function cals, I would usually write this as `my $x = (split /,/ => $str)[0]`

Comment: @Carl, a way you might think of it is that for `split( ... )` the parentheses only address the *call* -> you want to call split with these arguments. Tacking a `[0]` onto that makes little sense. However `( split ... )` addresses the value *returned*, which is really what you want to index.

Comment: This is helpful.  But unexpectedly, when I tried to print the result directly instead of assigning to a variable, like this: `print (split /,/, $comma_separated)[0];`, I got: `syntax error at test.pl line 3, near ")["`

Comment: @jdhildeb That's because in your case the opening parentheses are interpreted as enclosing the arguments to the print function.  You can either wrap the entire expression in another layer of parentheses (ie `print ((...)[0])`) or put a plus sign in front of the parentheses to make it a single argument to print (ie `print +(...)`).

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.

Comment: @sean Thanks! Now I know. I was trying to print the year using `localtime` and was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

Just like you can do this:

```
($a, $b, $c) = @array;
```

You can do this:

```
my($a) = split /,/, $comma_separated;
```

`my $a` on the LHS (left hand side) is treated as scalar context.  `my($a)` is list context.  Its a single element list so it gets just the first element returned from `split`.

It has the added benefit of auto-limiting the split, so there's no wasted work if `$comma_separated` is large.

Comment: Perl already performs this optimization automatically.  From "perldoc -f split": "When assigning to a list, if LIMIT is omitted, or zero, Perl supplies a LIMIT one larger than the number of variables in the list, to avoid unnecessary work."